# How to write an index/match function for dates and times that finds/returns the first value that is greater or less than the search value?

Tags: arrays, r, excel, indexing, match

I have a simple excel array function that I am struggling to get to work in R.

The excel function is an INDEX/MATCH function looking to return the relevant environmental variable from the first date and time point greater (or less than) 
the date and time that species abundance was recorded.

This is the excel formula:

```
{=INDEX('the environmental variable range i.e. temperature',
MATCH('date'+'time',from the'date range'+'time range',1))}

  1 specifies less than and requires the data to be sorted smallest to 
  largest while -1 specifies greater than and requires the data to be sorted 
  largest to smallest.
```

I am wondering how to recreate this in R?

I have loaded the abundance data (data) and the environmental data (EnVar) and converted the DataTime columns in each to a date time format using as.POSIXct

```
data$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(data$DateTime,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

I then ordered them using the xts package:

```
d <- xts(data, order.by = data$DateTime)
v <- xts(EnVar, order.by = EnVar$DateTime)
```

I have been trying to figure out how to index the correct row before trying to fit it into a loop function.

I started trying to use the match function:

```
d$DateTime[1] %in% v$DateTime
```

The problem with this is the date and times from d are not exactly the same as in t and I cant figure out how to add a greater or less than function to the match function.

I then found the which and which.min/max functions:

```
min(which(v$DateTime > d$DateTime[1]))
```

This returns an error "no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf", however if I replace d$DateTime[1] with the value of d$DateTime[1] it works:

```
min(which(v$DateTime > "2015-12-04 10:00:00"))
```

and returns the correct index potition (14 in this case). Though I don't know why?

I have also tried:

```
Position(v$DateTime > d$DateTime[1],t)
```

But this returns an error.

I have also looked into the dplyr package and the left_join function, however this (from my testing) only works if the date and times match across the data files (which they do not).

Finally I tried something like:

```
subset(v,which(abs(d$DateTime[i]-v$DateTime[i])==min(abs(d$DateTime[i]- 
v$DateTime[i]))))$temperature
```

But this only works if the two files are of the same length (which they are not).

Any solutions or pointers and help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem!

It's definitely not a very pretty solution but it works and gives me the output that I need. I thought I'd share what I found, just in case anyone is looking for a way to do this. However, I am sure there are better ways to do this, I just haven't figured any out.

Load your data (data) and your environmental variable(s) (var eg tempvar), with the DateTime columns (Dtime) as characters.

Then convert these to the correct format using `as.POSIXct` e.g.:

```
data$DTime <- as.POSIXct(data$DTime,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

then order these by date:

```
d <- xts(data, order.by = data$DTime)
v <- xts(tempvar, order.by = tempvar$DTime)
```

Create a vector of each of the date columns:

```
var <- as.vector(v$Dtime)
data <- as.vector(d$Dtime)
```

Then create this pipe function:

```
"%GT%" <- function(x, y) min(which(x > y))
```

to index the minimum value where x is > y

create a blank vector to then fill with this for loop and the pipe function we just made:

```
FirstValueGreaterThan <- as.vector(mode="integer",0)

for (i in 1:length(data)) {
  FirstValueGreaterThan[i] <- var %GT% data[i]
}
```

Finally, create a new data frame sub setting by row number (which are stored in FirstValueGreaterThan)

```
variable.eg.temp.greaterThan <- tempvar[FirstValueGreaterThan,]
```

if you want the first values less than, simply minus 1 row from the FirstValueGreaterThan:

```
variable.eg.temp.greaterThan <- tempvar[FirstValueGreaterThan-1,]
```

Then these can be amended onto your main data frame just like usual:

```
data$newdata <- variable.eg.temp.greaterThan$temp or Dtime...
```